# Async flux store operations

Tags: reactjs, react-native, lovefield

I am using the Flux library to provide a dispatcher and stores. However, I am using Google's Lovefield as a means of being an in memory bank.

The problem is that Lovefield's APIs are entirely async, therefore I can not emit changes or perform waitFor.

Any suggestions for a better design pattern?